# Changing permissions on a file

Tags: linux, file, permissions, root, file-permissions

If a file has the following permissions:
`-rwxr--r-- jim group other file.txt`
And `jim` is a non-root account, is there any reason why a `g+x` to the `file.txt` from another user would fail?

Answer (score 2):

The only people that can change the permissions of files are the people that own the files (in your case, jim) and the root user. This is to prevent users from doing something malicious, like changing the permission of someone else's file to r/w and then deleting everything in the file, or something similar.

Comment: So what would be the proper way to give the permissions I need in case `jim` accidentally created such restricted set of permissions? E.g. did not have `umask` correctly set

Comment: If you have access to the root account, log in as root and run the command. Otherwise you'll have to log in as jim.